# Linux - How to distribute as portable a root-only GUI application

Tags: linux, polkit, pkexec

With *portable* i mean an application that can be used for example for an USB drive, and don't require to 'touch' the OS file-system for run.

Under Windows, I can distribute a `.zip -> .exe -> .manifest file` with "requestedExecutionLevel" xml tag. Portable and request password via UAC graphically.

Under macOS, I can distribute a `.tar.gz > .App -> key in info.plist`. Portable and request password graphically.

Under Linux?

The correct procedure is a `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions policy file` and execute a binary with `pkexec`.
But it presume an installation to write the policy file (.deb or .rpm for example) and break portability.

We cannot rely on `gksu/kdesu/beesu` or similar, are deprecated and cannot be installed in recent distro (pkexec it's the recommended way).

We cannot tell (via `pkexec` command-line args) a local .policy file.

So, it's impossible under Linux to develop a portable application that require root privileges and GUI?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Can't you just provide "``run.sh``" script that checks if ``pkexec`` exists and, if yes, runs ``pkexec --user root ./yourapp`` or runs ``sudo ./yourapp`` otherwise?

Comment: What's wrong with just setting the ownership and mode of the executable?  As in, make it owned by root, with mode 0700?

Comment: Alternatively, if you're in control of the program then what about making it check at startup that its effective UID is 0?

Comment: pkexec without a specific policy file (that require a specific path of executable to match) have a lots of issue when launcing a UI application. Is the reason about why exists "allow_gui" in polkit policy.

Comment: "sudo ./yourapp" from terminal throw in a lots of distro "Could not open display". As above, the reason about "allow_gui" in polkit policy.